# Elementary OS on iMac works great but

Tags: hardware

...what can I use for fan control?
I need something SUPER EASY!
Putting EOS on the iMac is really just an experiment and it will only be used for basic stuff like web browsing.
I just need to set the fans to a certain percentage and be done with it.
As it stands now, they are full speed >.<

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/datcuandrei/MacLinuxUtils

Instructions can be found on the readme of the project.

If that doesn't work, there's this guide that might help: https://datcu-andrei-2.gitbook.io/maclinuxfancontrol/linux-alternatives